# Unix shell: Multi-level sort in opposite directions

Tags: shell, sorting

I have a directory full of plain text files that have tags on the first line, and I want to get a list of the tags and their frequency. I've extracted the tags and sorted them into a big list; let's say it looks like this:

```
apple
banana
banana
banana
banana
orange
orange
kumquat
pomegranate
pineapple
pineapple
pineapple
```

I then pipe it through `uniq -c` to transform it into a list with counts:

```
      1 apple
      4 banana
      2 orange
      1 kumquat
      1 pomegranate
      3 pineapple
```

I'd now like to sort it, first by number in reverse order (largest numbers first), and then in *forwards* alphabetical order. I try to do this by piping through `sort -bnr` (ignore leading whitespace, numerical sort, in reverse order), but the `-r` applies to the letter part as well:

```
      4 banana
      3 pineapple
      2 orange
      1 pomegranate
      1 kumquat
      1 apple
```

I thought about the `-k` option to sort by multiple fields, which I just learned about the other day, but it looks like the reversal can't be applied separately for different`-k` options (perhaps it just puts the output through `tac` or something?). Piping it through a second `sort` doesn't work because it ignores the previous sort and mixes up the numerical part again.

Ideally the solution would still use `sort` and `uniq`, but I'm open to switching to a different tool if necessary. This may end up in a script, though, so a solution requiring interactive tools is out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, found an answer already because I started randomly browsing items in the "related" sidebar! Turns out you can use parameters after field specifiers to apply them only to that field -- I read that part of the man page but evidently didn't read very carefully, because I missed:

> OPTS is one or more single-letter ordering options [bdfgiMhnRrV],
>   which override global ordering options for that key.  If no key is 
>   given, use the entire line as the key.

Final command:

```
sort -bk 1rn -k 2
```